# Struggling to find how many incongruent solutions modulo $pq$ does $x^2 \equiv 1\pmod{pq}$ have?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am struggling to solve this problem:

How many incongruent solutions modulo $pq$ does $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{pq}$ have?

Someone hinted at using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but I don't see how it can be applied here, as the Chinese Remainder Theorem has to do with a system of congruences, and this is just a single congruence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rigorous proof of how many solutions exist to $x^{2} \equiv 1 \mod pq$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001556/rigorous-proof-of-how-many-solutions-exist-to-x2-equiv-1-mod-pq)